# Calling a method with the multiple arguments in a template

Tags: python, django

How can I call a method, pass multiple parameters to it and render the result in a html template? I can't find a simple solution which works in all circumstantials. I'm aware about `@register.filter` and `@register.simple_tag` but there's alway an error being thrown.  If it's not thing, it's another. For example, simple_tag works when I render it, but throws an error when I call `if`.

So how can I call a method from an html template in the following ways:

```
{{method1(a, b)}}  
{% if method1(a, b) == some_value %}  {{method1(a, b)}} {%endif%}
```

Note I don't need advice like "you're doing something wrong, you should change your architecture" because that's not the case here. I just a simple way to do what I want. In Rails, for example, I can do it very, very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an **assignment tag** to assign the value received from the template tag into a variable which then can be used anywhere in the template.

```
@register.assignment_tag
def method1(a,b):
    ...
```

Then in your template you can call this template tag and assign its value to a variable `method_value`.

```
{% method1 a b as method_value %}
```

Then use this variable in the template.

```
{{method_value}}

{% if method_value == some_value %}  {{method_value}} {%endif%}
```